# Adding authentication to JMeter REST request

Tags: rest, jmeter

I've spent the better part of today trying to get this working, and still haven't been successful. I have a simple case - I'd just like to send one GET request to my web-service. But no matter what I do, I can't get it to authenticate. I've tried all kinds of combinations of Authorization Manager, Cookie Manager, Header Manager... To no avail.

I've boiled it down this simplest test:

```
Thread Group
---->HTTP Authorization Manager
---->HTTP Request
---->View Results Tree
```

What could I possibly be missing?? I've tried several URLs for the Authorization Manager, and currently have it set to `https://[domain]:[port]`.
I've filled in Username and Password, and that's it.

Comment: Does your site have Basic authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure I know the difference. I normally use SoapUI, and tell it to preemptively send authentication information.

Comment: I can say we use LDAP authentication. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I've added a HTTP Request to the login page (outside of webservices), and verified that the HTTP Authorization Manager does authenticate me. But the very next request, the web service request, still says "Not Authorized".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable pre-emptive authentication, use HTTPClient 3.1 implementation of http request.
Then change the files below to add:

- jmeter.properties:

  `httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters`
- httpclient.parameters:

  `http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true`